# DynamoDB Conditional Update Expression for Nested Objects

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

#### **Case:**

I am aware this question is a bit long (sorry for that). I think a detailed description explains my case better.
I receive device data from a streaming endpoint. Each payload in stream includes multiple data entity. I create following structure to be stored in dynamo

```
db_pk = str(msg.get('key'))
db_sk = str(msg.get('sortKey'))
area_id = str(msg.get('area'))
## other entities in following mapped_values...

mapped_values = {
    startTime: {
        'alert_msg': alert,
        'area ': area_id,
        'speed': speed,
        'state': state,
        'startTime': startTime,
        'duration': duration,
        'inspector': inspector_id
    }
}
# Data item
lt_item = {
    'id': db_pk,
    'serialNo': db_sk,
    'value_map': [mapped_values]
}
```

I use the following update statement to create a mapping of incoming data in each payload.

```
table = dynamo_db.Table('device')
table.update_item(
        Key = {
            'id': db_pk,
            'serialNo': db_sk
        },
        UpdateExpression = 'SET #value_map = list_append(#value_map, :mapped_values)',
        ConditionExpression = 'attribute_exists(#value_map)',
        ExpressionAttributeValues = {
            ':mapped_values': [mapped_values]
        },
        ExpressionAttributeNames = {
            '#value_map': 'value_map'
        }
    )
```

### **Current Result**

The above update expression creates a map of messages under the `value_map` key in dynamo, and whenever a new message received, it is appended into the map like the following:

```
{
   "id": "KD_125",
   "serialNo": "KDCRT-231"
   "value_map": [
      {
         "2019-05-29 14:36:03": { #first msg in payload
             "alert_msg": "0x12 LOGICAL ERROR AT DIRECTION SELECT SIGNAL",
             "area": "TX-112",
             "speed": "65",
             "startTime": "2019-05-29 14:36:03",
             "state": "ACTIVE",
             "duration": "None"
             "inspector": "None"
             }
      },
      {
        "2019-05-29 14:36:03": { # second msg, same timestamp with first one
             "alert_msg": "0x12 LOGICAL ERROR AT DIRECTION SELECT SIGNAL",
             "area": "None",
             "speed": "None",
             "startTime": "2019-05-29 14:36:03",
             "state": "PASSIVE",
             "duration": "1200"
             "inspector" "422TX19"
             }
        }
          #another message with different timestamp and data values
     ]
}
```

### **Problem and Requirement**

Some of the messages are sent with same timestamp (`startTime`). If `state='ACTIVE'` in message, it includes all data except **`duration`** and **`inspector`**; and If `state='PASSIVE'`, it includes `duration, inspector` and others except **`area`** and **`speed`** (see above sample).

If the **same** `timestamp` is sent in the payload, I need to replace the `None` values (`duration` and `inspector`) and `state` of `'ACTIVE'`state message with the `'PASSIVE'`state message instead of creating two objects with the same `timestamp`. So the final shape should be like:

```
{
   "id": "KD_125",
   "serialNo": "KDCRT-231"
   "value_map": [
      {
         "2019-05-29 14:36:03": { 
             "alert_msg": "0x12 LOGICAL ERROR AT DIRECTION SELECT SIGNAL",
             "area": "TX-112",
             "speed": "65",
             "startTime": "2019-05-29 14:36:03",
             "state": "PASSIVE", # updated from PASSIVE state msg
             "duration": "1200" # updated values from PASSIVE state msg
             "inspector": "422TX19" # updated values from PASSIVE state msg
             }
      }
      # other messages with different timestamps
   ]
}
```

I tried different [update expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html) such as `if_not_exists`. In addition, tested with

```
ExpressionAttributeNames = {
            '#value_map': 'value_map.startTime'
        }
```

option.. But no success so far. I hope someone can suggest me a way to make this update..

Comment: I think part of your problem is that you are building a list of maps - what you really want is a map of maps (because element names in a map are unique). Then you can build a condition expression around attribute_exists or attribute_not_exists (using the full path of the nested map). Does that make sense?

Comment: I am testing the same direction as well. I guess with one update statement, the logic will be complicated. So perhaps, multiple if-else conditions and corresponding update_expressions might work. I will put my answer if I reach sth.